# How to profile wall-clock time?

Tags: linux, time, c++, profiling

In my program, real time duration is sometimes as much as 3 times that of cpu time. This is a single thread application that does a lot of memory allocation and NFS base read/write. So my doubt is that it is either mem-swap or NFS read-write that is slowing things down.
For example, the following is the output of `/usr/bin/time a.out`

```
2165.32user 64.93system 6036.33elapsed
```

Is there any profiling tool for real time? I know and have used multiple tools for cpu time profiling, but am not sure if there is anything that can help and point out NFS / mem-swap or any other wall clock slowdowns.

My program is written in C++

**EDIT** : `/usr/bin/time` gives me a summary at the end - I am not looking for that. I am looking for a way to correlate the real-time consumption during specific program blocks of my application. A profiler like collect/gprof that can tell me things like

- the area where most context switches are happening due to waits.
- specific functions where NFS access is happening.

Since my system is dedicated, I am not worried about other processes that might impact these profiles.

Comment: `man -s 1 time` (Linux Mint 18.1) lists 24 options that make stats on various resources. E.g. %F Number of major, or I/O-requiring, page faults that occurred while the process was running. You might see if any (or all) of those give you insight. You might need to search for what the terms mean -- it's all Greek to me. %r/%s might tell you about NFS activity, for example.

Comment: I would say this is a programming question better suited for StackOverflow. However, if you migrate there it'll probably get closed as a duplicate of [How can I profile C++ code running on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/375913/2344631)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly.. but looks like you might need strace ...

Example:

Here, say if I have a process with process id 1055 then doing something like this :

```
 neo $ sudo strace -w -c -p1055

strace: Process 1055 attached
^Cstrace: Process 1055 detached
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 77.38    5.738820         534     10730           read
  5.35    0.396752         114      3480           clone
  4.17    0.309514          10     30741           rt_sigprocmask
  2.31    0.171203          13     12761           close
  1.56    0.115981          16      6960      3480 wait4
  1.47    0.108800          10     10441           rt_sigaction
  1.43    0.106307           8     11890           fcntl
  0.98    0.072344          19      3770           openat
  0.86    0.063769          18      3480           write
  0.85    0.062820          18      3480           pipe
  0.84    0.062443          15      4060           dup2
  0.67    0.049338           9      5220           lseek
  0.57    0.042007          11      3770      3770 ioctl
  0.49    0.036669          10      3480           rt_sigreturn
  0.47    0.035150          10      3480           fchmod
  0.29    0.021420          12      1740           unlink
  0.25    0.018666          10      1740           getpid
  0.06    0.004745          16       290           stat
```

do read more here:

```
man strace
```

as well as here:

https://strace.io/

Comment: Would you mind editing your post to include an example on how to use `strace` for the OPs problem? Otherwise it might be considered a "link-only-answer" and attract delete votes.

Comment: well .. I thought the command is enough to dig more into.. but here it is .. updated with example...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you’ll find [`perf timechart`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-timechart.1.html) very useful. By default it records CPU and process state, and draws a chart showing how that state changes over time:

[image: perf timechart]

This shows the CPU occupation at the top, and processes underneath — blue means “running”, yellow means the process is waiting for a CPU, red means the process is blocked on I/O, gray means the process is sleeping. `perf timechart` outputs SVG which can be zoomed to whatever level of detail you want.

It can also trace I/O (disk and network), and branches.

`perf` has other modules which will help examine details; `perf record` can be record timestamp and present time-based information, using whatever events you’re interested in (if your system supports them).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are asking but this is similar to `/usr/bin/time` and only measures the wall clock:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s%N)
"$@"
end=$(date +%s%N)
echo "$(($end - $start)) nanoseconds elapsed"
```

Save it to `wallclock` and run it for example with

```
$ ./wallclock sleep 1
1006622540 nanoseconds elapsed
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a wall-clock profiler for some time, too. The tool I found meets the expectation most is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/55146/78636. Its principle is very straightforward: start the process from GDB and then interrupt GDB at a fixed interval to record the backtrace.